# Which way is faster in initializing registers in a microcontroller?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

This question came to my mind while writing some firmware for a PIC microcontroller.

There are two methods I know to initialize registers in a microcontroller. Say for an example, if we are initializing a port as outputs, one way is to write a command like the following and it will assign `1` to every bit in TRISx register

**Method 1**

```
TRISX = 0xFF;
```

The same thing can be done by assigning bits individually.

**Method 2**

```
_TRISX0 = 1;
_TRISX1 = 1;
_TRISX2 = 1;
...
_TRISX7 = 1;
```

My question is, will it get treated as same by compiler and the time taken to complete both the operations are same? Or does method 1 take one clock cycle while method 2 takes 8 (I mean ~8 times slower)?

I tried reading [X16 compiler guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj71cPaqfLiAhVMvo8KHaJfBk0QFjABegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microchip.com%2Fstellent%2Fgroups%2Ftechpub_sg%2Fdocuments%2Fdevicedoc%2Fen559023.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2kznvx__AkE_OuPhk7I_Tj) but couldn't find any tips.

Comment: Why not inspecting the generated machine code?

Comment: Machine code generated by compiler is a hex file right?

Comment: A hex file is rather the binary interpretation of the raw machine code, expressed in an ASCII format. They are not human-friendly reading. What you should be looking at instead is the disassembly - any decent tool chain has a disassembler option. Good ones show the disassembly together with the C source. Some good debuggers also have this option. At the very least you'll be able to see the raw disassembly in any debugger.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hardware registers are always `volatile` qualified and the compiler is not allowed to optimize code containing `volatile` access. So if you write to them 8 times, then 8 writes is what you get. This is of course much slower than 1 write.

In addition, it is very bad practice to write to registers several times in a row just as if they were a temporary variable in RAM. Hardware registers tend to have all manner of subtle side-effects. They can have "write-once" attribute or only accept writes in certain modes. By writing to them in several steps, you make a habit of creating all manner of crazy, subtle problems caused by incorrect register setups.

Correct practice is to write to registers once, or as few times as necessary.

For example, you may think that a data direction register as in your example is a pretty dumb one with no side-effects. But often GPIO hardware needs some time to toggle the port circuits, from the point where you write to the data direction register to the point where you access the I/O port. So it is possible that several writes would stall the port needlessly.

Assuming `REGISTER` is the name of the memory-mapped, `volatile`-qualified hardware register, then...

Don't do this:

```
MASK1 = calculation();
REGISTER |= MASK1;
MASK2 = calculation();
REGISTER |= MASK2;
```

Do this:

```
uintx_t reg_val=0; // temp variable in RAM
MASK1 = calculation();
reg_val |= MASK1;
MASK2 = calculation();
reg_val |= MASK2;
REGISTER = reg_val; // single write to the actual register
```

Comment: Beware that your answer is not applicable to everything in the embedded world. Some processors (and compilers) support bit manipulation; and, for example, some Renesas C compiler can optimize subsequent bit-writes on the same register (coalesces them).

Comment: @linuxfan Nope, the (conforming) compiler isn't allowed to do that on a volatile-qualified register. Suppose I want to disable an interrupt, then clear a status flag, and these bits are part of the same register. Merging those two bit instructions into one would change the meaning of the code. The intention is to let a pending interrupt finish and then clear the flag that the interrupt had set. If done in a single instruction, the interrupt would never be executed.

Comment: Or an even more obvious example: suppose I want to bit-bang something to shift registers through GPIO.

Comment: For example, this C compiler: https://www.renesas.com/us/en/doc/products/tool/002/rej10j1995_nc30_u.pdf says, at page 19, "-Ono_bit  -ONB  Suppresses optimization based on grouping of bit manipulations", or even "-ONLOC Suppresses the optimization that puts consecutive OR together. I am not saying that this compiler is perfect, but consider that C language has scarce support for bits.

Comment: @linuxfan The options you describe say just the same thing as me: suppress optimization, when optimization would break the intended program behavior.

Comment: Second way of writing is not the same functionality as the first one as the register is not read before writing back. Last line should be `REGISTER |= reg_val;` to have same kind of behavior.

Comment: I am not a specialist of PIC, but good compiler uses BSF/BCF (or so) instruction to access TRIS register for one bit setting instead of classical byte write instruction.
But result is the same, fast solution is `TRISX = 0xFF;`

Comment: @Lundin: This is not only 8 separate writes, but also 8 reads before the modification. Since it's volatile, it has to read it first. Someone here did this once with all the GPIO pin initialization on a Freescale/NXP MPC577x .. the code bloat was dramatic .. 56kB code compared to a static const GpioConfig[] and a for loop with just 2kB in total for ~300 pins.

Comment: @kesselhaus Not necessarily. Writing to a `volatile` register does not produce a read, as far as the C language is concerned. But in practice it might result in read-modify-write instructions. As for GPIO on MPC5x ("SIUL" etc), it's a quite weird peripheral to work with and I'm not surprised if code turns to crap as a result. Unless you are working with Freescale Processor Expert - if so, that's without doubt the source of your code bloat.

Comment: @Lundin Processor Expert was not used, just the mpc577x.h header with all the register definitions. Since there are so many bits to configure, a lot of developers think, it's easier to set the bits by name (e.g. xxx.B.OBE = 1; xxx.B.IBE = 0;), rather than using bitwise shift/and/or operations (e.g. xxx.R = (OBE_ON | IBE_OFF;). Unfortunately, a lot of developers nowadays do not seem to have certain sense of the constraints of embedded systems and write programs as if that would be a PC or HPC server with lots of memory and storage.

Comment: @kesselhaus Indeed, I recognize that problem too. Not only MPC5x got "PC-programmer friendly" registers, but lots of ARMs as well. But well, MPC5x is about as far from beginner-friendly as it gets, so if someone recruited rookies to program that one, that's the actual root of all problems.

Answer (score 7):

It will depend on the processor instruction set and the compiler. For the PIC18F45K20, for example, the `sdcc` compiler compiles the following

```c
TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 1;
```

to

```
BSF _TRISDbits, 0
```

while it compiles

```c
TRISD = 0xFF;
```

to

```
MOVLW   0xff
MOVWF   _TRISD
```

So in this case setting an individual bit is faster, because it does not involve placing a temporary value in the working register.

Not all instruction sets include a `BSF` instruction however, and some architectures would not require the use of the working register for the latter task.

P.S. The above examples are based on the output of the sdcc compiler, but I imagine the `xc8` and `xc16` compilers yield similar results.

P.P.S. When inspecting the generated assembly, bear in mind that some instructions consume more processor cycles than others. See datasheet for details.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is, you haven't provided C code to show how are those bits actually referenced. But let's say it's through union & struct of bit-fields.

The best way is to actually examine the ASM that the compiler generates. You do need to know your hw arch, but you would still need to look at the generated ASM to really know.

To assign just a single bit , say  _TRISX0=1; vs TRISX = 0x01;, depending on the arch and compiler, it is possible that compiler can generate more efficient  (less cycles and may be less instructions) code for just single bit assignment than entire register.
There is at least one such MCU/DSP processor and compiler, from TI, for which I know this is true.

For case when you have multiple (>1) statements, your Method 2,  with individual bit assignments, it is likely that your one-liner register assignment will be more or as efficient: if compiler deduces - wrongly or not - that all of those bit assignments assign to same register in sequence, it may replace them with one-liner as you could have in method 1.

I do not have PIC specifically in mind.  I'm advising to examine ASM for any MCU, when you care.

Comment: If the CPU supports bit instructions but generates a less efficient program for C code doing byte access of the register, the compiler is pretty horrible. You have the same situation on normal, byte-wise oriented CPUs with direct writes versus read-modify-write instructions. It is the compiler's job to pick the right one, not the C programmer.

Comment: @Lundin, by "byte-wise oriented CPU" do you mean CPU with 8-bit instructions and 8-bit registers?  I understand "It is the compiler's job to pick the right one, not the C programmer" but this does not work always for hardware programming.

Comment: @Lundin  "If the CPU supports bit instructions but generates a less efficient program for C code doing byte access of the register, the compiler is pretty horrible."   This depends on architecture - addressing modes, available instructions, and the register you accessing.  An efficient/1-cycle bitwise OR instruction to a byte register on an arch with otherwise 16-bit bit instructions may break your assertion.   A C's byte you thinking in - i.e. uint8_t - may not even map directly to hardware word or directly addressable memory.

Comment: The situation you talk about where writing a single bit instead of a whole register is only true for cores with single bit instructions, that are faster than byte-wise instructions.